# How can i make a ticking like noise (clock) using web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I am starting with basic whitenoise and I want to create a delay that makes it come on and off after every second like a clock. I'm then going to tweak the noise with different filters to alter the noise.

At the moment I have the noise with a low pas filter to change the frequency sound of the noise. Can someone help with my next step, it's my first time using stack overflow sorry if i haven't given enough info.

Here is my code:

html

```
<html>
  <input type="button" value="Start/Stop" id="StartStop">
  <input type="number"  min="1000" max="2000" value="1000" id="Filter">
  <script>
    let context= new AudioContext();
    StartStop.onclick = function() {
    if (context.state === 'suspended') context.resume();
    else context.suspend();
    }
    context.audioWorklet.addModule('mySound.js').then(() => {
      let myNoise = new AudioWorkletNode(context,'noise-generator');
      let myFilter = new AudioWorkletNode(context,'lowpass-filter',{parameterData:{frequency:1000}});
      Filter.oninput = function() {
        myFilter.parameters.get('frequency').value=this.value;
        FilterLabel.innerHTML = this.value ;
      }
      myNoise.connect(myFilter);
      myFilter.connect(context.destination);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

javascropt

```
registerProcessor('noise-generator',class extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process(inputs, outputs) {
    for (let i=0;i<outputs[0][0].length;++i)  outputs[0][0][i]=2*Math.random()-1;
    return true;
  }
});

registerProcessor('gain-processor',class extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  // Custom AudioParams can be defined with this static getter.
  static get parameterDescriptors() { return [{name:'gain',defaultValue:0.1}] }
//  constructor() { super() }  // The super constructor call is required
  process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    const input = inputs[0],output = outputs[0];
    for (let channel=0;channel<inputs[0].length;++channel)
      for (let i=0;i<input[channel].length;++i) output[channel][i] = input[channel][i] * parameters.gain[0];
    return true;
  }
});

registerProcessor('lowpass-filter', class extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  static get parameterDescriptors() { return [{name:'frequency',defaultValue:1000,minValue:0}]; }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.lastOut = 0;
  }
  process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    let input = inputs[0],output = outputs[0],coeff;
    let frequency = parameters.frequency;
    for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
      let inputChannel = input[channel],outputChannel = output[channel];
      coeff = 2 * Math.PI * frequency[0] / sampleRate;
      for (let i = 0; i < outputChannel.length; ++i) {
        outputChannel[i]=inputChannel[i] * coeff +(1-coeff)*this.lastOut;
        this.lastOut=outputChannel[i];
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

First off, I'd reduce complexity by using the builtin `GainNode` and `BiquadFilterNode` (or `IIRFilterNode`) instead of `AudioWorkletNode` to implement these.

To make the noise turn off and on every second, I'd use a looping AudioBufferSourceNode to create the regular off/on clicks and feed that into the `gain` AudioParam of the `GainNode`.  Something like this (totally untested!):

```
// Create buffer that's 1 sec long
let buffer = new AudioBuffer({sampleRate: context.sampleRate, length: context.sampleRate});
let data = buffer.getChannelData(0);
// Set the first few values of the buffer to 1.  You'll have to decide how many.
// This is basically a square wave with a short duty cycle.
data[0] = 1;

// Create the source that loops forever.
let tick = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: buffer});
tick.loop = true;

let gain = new GainNode(context, {gain: 0});
tick.connect(gain.gain);

// Start the source now.
tick.start();

// A Biquad filter instead of your worklet.  You'll have to choose the parameters.
let filt = new BiquadFilterNode(context);

// Connect up your noise source to the gain node, and connect the gain node
// to the destination:
myNoise.connect(filt).connect(gain).connect(context.destination);
```

The tick is 1 for a short time and that gets added to the gain of the `GainNode`.  Hence the gain of the node is 1 for a bit, then 0 for the rest of the time.  This is applied to your noise, so you get noise output for a bit then silence.

I think this is what you're asking for.